# Docutils for Django adding acknowledgements

Tags: python, django

I'm using python docutils for Django by adding it to the admin using the guide found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/

This hides most of the magic as you know. My question is how do I add new pages such as acknowledgements etc to the admin docs it creates? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct support for adding "standalone" pages, but you could easily just create a view (or use TemplateView) for each page you want to "create", and document them with the information you'd like to appear.

Comment: I don't have an example handy, but you would create a new page exactly as you create a page normally in Django, using a view and template. The difference is, your view documentation would be the content you want to add as an admindocs page.

Of course, at that point you may as well just create a "normal" Django page and include a link to it from one of your existing admindoc pages.